# How to animate object without Open GL ES?

Tags: java, android, animation

I am trying to make the movement of my snake smooth. Right now the movement is jumpy. This is how i have him moving....

```
public void advance() {
    SnakePart head = parts.get(0);               

    int len = parts.size() - 1;
    for(int i = len; i > 0; i--) {
        SnakePart before = parts.get(i-1);
        SnakePart part = parts.get(i);
        part.x = before.x;
        part.y = before.y;
    }
```

So basically i have it set to update every .5 seconds and advance one coordinate. Is there a way for me to make him move smoothly at one coordinate over .5 seconds without having to use Open GL ES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a TranslateAnimation if the "View" object gets not dragged by a finger tap